# " Substance with critical comments on style "?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have an admission test on 5th and the syllabus has a topic " Substance with critical comments on style " for 25 marks. I don't really understand what it says. Help ??

Comment: As you've tagged your question with " meaning in context", can you give more context ?

Comment: I'd suggest you ask the instructor.  Sounds like gibberish to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a particular lesson, story or chapter being referred to? In that case, 'Substance with critical comments on style' means that you need to provide an answer that contains the pros and cons of the particular style that the author has used in his piece. You need to analyse the piece, weigh the advantages and disadvantages of the style, state where the inappropriateness of the style seems prominent, whether the style is consistent or not etc. Writing styles include narration, description, persuasive and expository. This may help: http://literarydevices.net/style/

Comment: My pleasure! All the very best for your exam!